# Fragment: onCreateView - не сохраняет View

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть приложение, состоящее из `MainActivity` и 3х фрагментов на нём(с `TabLayout` и `PagerAdapter`).

**В приложении я работаю с БД:**

в 1м фрагменте нахожу слово и добавляю его в избранное;

во 2м фрагменте в реальном времени отображаю список избранных слов;

При запуске, так как фрагменты 1 и 2 в табах 1 и 2, они оба запускаются.

Но через пару секунд `view` из блока ниже становится `null`, если её не сделать `static`
**Как быть? С одного фрагмента обновлять адаптер в другом фрагменте через МайнАктивити приходится костыльно**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_favorite, container, false);
    rvFavorite = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvFavorite);
    return view;
}
```

**Вот код с MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private ViewPager pager;
private MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ManagerDataBase.getInstance().openBase();

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.general);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.star);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.setting);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null && intent.getIntExtra("key", 0) == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Данные обновленны", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Нет интернет соединения", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void updateFavorite(){
    Fragment fr = pagerAdapter.getItem(1);
    if(fr != null && fr instanceof Favorite){
        Favorite f = (Favorite) fr;
        f.updateData();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ManagerDataBase.getInstance().closeBase();
}
}
```

**Код с 1го фрагмента:**

```
public class General extends Fragment {

// тут какой-то код

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_general, container, false);

    //инициализация вьюшек здесь

    star_empty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ManagerDataBase.getInstance().insertFavorite(idFavorite, langFavorite, transFavorite, wordFavorite);
            ((MainActivity)context).updateFavorite();
        }
    });

    star_full.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ManagerDataBase.getInstance().deleteFavorite(idFavorite);
            ((MainActivity)context).updateFavorite();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

**Код 2го врагмента:**

```
public class Favorite extends Fragment {
private Context context;
private RecyclerView rvFavorite;
private ArrayList<FavoriteObject> favoriteObjects = new ArrayList<>();
private FavoriteAdapter adapter;
private TextView tvFav;
private static View view; //TODO: Без этого костыля "static" не сохраняется вьюшка

public static Favorite newInstance() {
    Favorite fragmentFirst = new Favorite();
    fragmentFirst.setRetainInstance(true);
    return fragmentFirst;
}

// тут онАттач и онКреате

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_favorite, container, false);
    rvFavorite = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvFavorite);
    tvFav = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFav);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    rvFavorite.setLayoutManager(llm);
    updateData();
    Log.e("TAG", "Fav. onCreateView:");
    return view;
}

public void updateData() {
    if (view != null) {
        if (rvFavorite == null) {
            rvFavorite = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvFavorite);
        }
        if (tvFav == null){
            tvFav = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFav);
        }

        favoriteObjects = ManagerDataBase.getInstance().getFavorite2();
        if (favoriteObjects.size() == 0) {
            rvFavorite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvFav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            rvFavorite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        adapter = new FavoriteAdapter(context, favoriteObjects);
        rvFavorite.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

}
```

**ФрагментПейджерАдаптер:**

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private Fragment currentFragment;
public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
    return currentFragment;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            currentFragment = General.newInstance();
            break;
        case 1:
            currentFragment = Favorite.newInstance();
            break;
        case 2:
            currentFragment = Setting.newInstance();
            break;
        default:
            return null;

    }
    return currentFragment;
    //return FragmentAdapter.newInstance(position, "");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private Fragment currentFragment;
private List<Fragment> listFragments = new ArrayList<>(3);
public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
    return currentFragment;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            if (listFragments.get(position) != null) {
                currentFragment = listFragments.get(position);
            } else {
                currentFragment = General.newInstance();
                listFragments.set(position, currentFragment);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (listFragments.get(position) != null) {
                currentFragment = listFragments.get(position);
            } else {
                currentFragment = Favorite.newInstance();
                listFragments.set(position, currentFragment);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (listFragments.get(position) != null) {
                currentFragment = listFragments.get(position);
            } else {
                currentFragment = Setting.newInstance();
                listFragments.set(position, currentFragment);
            }
            break;
        default:
            currentFragment = General.newInstance(); //или какой нибудь другой
    }
    return currentFragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}


}
```

Выдает такую ошибку

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                 at diit.ru.slovnik.adapters.MyFragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(MyFragmentPagerAdapter.java:33)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:109)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1182)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1375)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2127)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1243)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1479)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6050)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:608)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Comment: В пейджер адаптере в методе getItem(int position) вы все время пересоздаете фрагменты, на 95% уверен что проблема растет от сюда.

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii, а как бы Вы поступили на моём месте?

Comment: Сохраняйте фрагменты в коллекцию в адаптере. Добавляйте их, если их нет, берите существующие, если уже созданы. `position` Вам в этом прекрасно поможет.

Comment: @Vladimir имеете ввиду ArrayList<Fragment>?

Comment: @zayn1991 да.  фрагмента в списке или массиве

Comment: @VladimirParfenov у меня не получилось сообразить с условиями заполнения массива, ` if (!fragmentList.get(position).isAdded()) {fragmentList.add(position, Favorite.newInstance());}` ругается на пустоту массива

Comment: @zayn1991 значит вы не инициализировали лист. Сразу создайте лист размером кол-ва фрагментов, в Fragment getItem(int position) в свиче проверяйте если в листе в ячейке position == null создавайте фрагмент и кладите его в эту ячейку(и тут же используйте) else берете фрагмент из этой ячейки и используете его.

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii, всёравно ругается на ту же ошибку, при задании размера массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраняете фрагменты, а потом переиспользуете их.

```
List<Fragment> listFragments = Arrays.asList(new Fragment[3]);
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            if (listFragments.get(position) != null) {
                currentFragment = listFragments.get(position);
            } else {
                currentFragment = General.newInstance();
                listFragments.set(position, currentFragment);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (listFragments.get(position) != null) {
                currentFragment = listFragments.get(position);
            } else {
                currentFragment = Favorite.newInstance();
                listFragments.set(position, currentFragment);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (listFragments.get(position) != null) {
                currentFragment = listFragments.get(position);
            } else {
                currentFragment = Setting.newInstance();
                listFragments.set(position, currentFragment);
            }
            break;
        default:
            currentFragment = General.newInstance(); //или какой нибудь другой
    }
    return currentFragment;
}
```

Comment: ругается на масив всёравно(`listFragments `)

Comment: Как "ругается"? В чем проблема?

Comment: в первом же case: ругается 'listFragments.get(position) != null' на null object reference

Comment: @zayn1991 проверил только что, ни на что не ругается, это рабочий код. Возможно вы не инициализировали лист фрагментов? Хотя по идее это не должно выдавать ошибку при компиляции. Вы точно сделали именно так(List<Fragment> listFragments = new ArrayList<>(3);) ?

Comment: добавил код и лог в UPDATE

Comment: @zayn1991  Cтранно, я вроде бы когда то так делал. Ну да ладно, вообщем нужно немного изменить инициализацию листа фрагментов. List<Fragment> listFragments = Arrays.asList(new Fragment[3]);